# Define the image of the function $f :\Bbb Z \times \Bbb N →\Bbb R$ given by $f(a, b) = \frac{a−4}{7b}$?

Tags: proof-verification

$\Bbb Z$ - integers
$\Bbb N$ - natural numbers (starting from 1)
$\Bbb R$ - real numbers

I believe the answer is the set of real numbers ($\Bbb R$), seeing as $b$ will not equal $0$ as the set of natural numbers start from $1$. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not surjective so the image is not $\Bbb R$; in fact, no irrational number is in im $f$, because a quotient of integers is never irrational.

If $a \in \Bbb Z$ and $b \in \Bbb N$, then $\dfrac{a-4}{7b} \in \Bbb Q$. This shows that im $f \subseteq \Bbb Q$.

On the other hand, any rational number $\frac cd$ is in the image of $f$:

Let $b \in \Bbb N$. Then

$$f\left(\frac {7cb}d +4, b\right)=\dfrac{\left(\frac {7cb}d+4\right)-4}{7b}=\frac cd$$

Hence, $\Bbb Q \subseteq $ im $f$.

This means that im $f$ is $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: in f(7cb/d + 4, b) <-why is b left to it's own?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you mean. I left it arbitrary because it doesn't actually matter what $b \in \Bbb N$ you choose because it cancels out (to check this just simplify the quotient in the answer). You can check that choosing $b=1$ or $b=2$ gives you the same image, or that $f\left(\frac {7c}d +4, 1\right)=f\left(\frac {14c}d +4, 2\right)$.

Comment: You're welcome! But I'm female, actually; it's not usually a good idea to try to guess the gender of the person behind the screen :)